# How do i count checkboxes and divide on number?

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm trying to count a brands sales for google sheet but i couldn't because what i want is kinda strange
[image]
sum orders value if brand is true but if there's 2 are true you divide on 2 if there are 3 you divide on 3 etc
Thank you

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide your value by :
`COUNTIF([range];TRUE)`

In your example, it'll be :
`COUNTIF(E2:I2;TRUE)`

So in `D2` you'll have :
`=1000/COUNTIF(E2:I2;TRUE)`